# SSAS Tabular Model - Partition Refresh and Schedule

Tags: ssas, cube, tabular, ssas-tabular

I have 5 dimensions and a fact table in my DWH. Build SSAS Tabular Model cube and created Partitions for my fact table. Say 2015, 2016 and 2017.Then, deploy my cube in my server. And, I am creating a job to refresh my data for the partition 2017 alone. Not the entire data.

How to achieve this by scheduling a job to refresh all my dimensions and 2017 partition alone?

Thanks in advance. Please anyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to process a specific partition you can do it with a xmla script.

How to retrieve it?

From Management studio, Right click on your fact and choose Partitions

[image]

Choose your partition (in my example I only have one) and click on the process icon.

[image]

1. Choose your partition
2. Select your process mode (In your case, process full)
3. Click and generate your XMLA code

[image]

Your XMLA Code:

[image]

Now you can create your job:

[image]

Otherwise you can create one SSIS Package and use an **Analysis Services Execute DDL Task**
[image]

I did some test and screenshot, but I saw that microsoft did already a nice explanation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/schedule-ssas-administrative-tasks-with-sql-server-agent

I hope that I helped you.

Regards,
Arnaud

Comment: Thanks Arnaud. I have implemented this. Very useful.